# Azure SQL - error while importing the bacpac file

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, data-migration, bacpac

I am trying to import a bacpac file into the Azure SQL server, however the import is not happening and it is also not giving any explicit error in the process.

If I check under deployments in the resource group, it gives the below failure message:

Performs a database extension operation - Failed

Apart from this there is no explicit failure message that can indicate what went wrong.
Also, "No Import/Export history is available" is coming under Import/Export history for the Azure SQL server.

Comment: what is the size of DB ( not the size of BACPAC but the DB from which this BACPAC is generated )? If DB size is more than 32 GB, try connecting the Azure SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio --> Create an Empty DB --> Right click on Empty DB and then import BACPAC file.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#limitations),
There is certain limitation when you import database using `BACPAC file`.

- Elastic pool doesn't enable you to import databases.
- When Allow access to Azure services is set to OFF, Import-Export Service is unavailable.

As you are not getting what is exact error causing the problem, you can raise support ticket to Microsoft from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) for more assistance on this.